# Why does the nested if statement output true when there is no condition requirement?

Tags: c

I am struggling with the nested "if statement" I do not know why it is displaying true when there is no condition requirement and when I change the return value it is displaying false. Also why there is no difference when I change the function's primitive type from int to char?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int random(char z[]);

int main() {

    char *x ="Tup";
    char *y ="Nope";
    printf("%s\n", x);
    printf("%d\n", random("Hi"));


    if(random("random char")){
        if(x){
            printf("True");
        }
    }else if(y){
        printf("False");
    }


    return 0;
}
int random(char z[])
{
    char a[3] ="yak";

    return a[0] == 'y';
}
```

Comment: `a[0] == 'y'` is always true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `random` function returns the result of the condition `a[0] == 'y'`.  Since you define `a` as `char a[3] ="yak"` this is always true.

Because of this, the condition of `if (random("random char"))` is true so the `if` section is entered.  Then `if(x)` is evaluated.  `x` points to the string constant `"Tup"`, meaning it has a non-zero value, causing the condition to be true.  So `"True" is then printed.